# Match the text between two words (Words don't repeat in matched text)

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I have the following as my Input,

**Input**

```
Random Line 1
Random Line 2
From: person1@example.com
Date: 01-01-2011
To: friend@example.com
   Subject: One
Random Line 3
Random Line 4
From: person2@example.com
   Subject: Two
Random Line 5
From: person3@example.com
   Subject: Three
This is the end
```

The following is my expected matched text,

**Expected Output**

```
From: person2@example.com
   Subject: Two
```

**Note:** There may be zero or multiple lines in between *From: person2@example.com* and *Subject: Two*

I tried with the regular expression,

```
/(From.*?Subject:\s*Two)/m
```

The above regex matches from the first **From**. Can anyone help me in matching the expected output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are lines between `"From: person2@example.com"` and `"Subject: Two"`, do you want those lines returned (as well as `"From:..\n"` and `"Subject: Two"`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `.*` before your regex to get only the expected two lines.

```
.*(From.*?Subject:\s*Two)
```

Because of greedy quantifier `*`, regex engine matches upto the last `From` string(ie, the one before the line which contains the string `Two`). Then from the string `From` upto the string `Two` is captured into a group(Non-greedy quantifier is used. so it do a shortest match).

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/0HcDQ2Q8nd)

Comment: @Mohamed It works if you have many lines in-between From: person2@example.com and Subject: Two.

Comment: If you are returning everything between (the required) `"From"` and `"Subject:\s*Two"`, I don't see the need for the non-greedy modifier (assuming there is at most one line containing `"Subject: Two"`, and if we don't know if that's true the question is unclear).

Comment: @CarySwoveland you mean this `.*(From.*Subject:\s*Two)`?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have only one newline between the first and second line:

```
/(From[^\n]*\n\s*Subject:\s*Two)/m
```

[see here](http://rubular.com/r/dB9lfD6iMy)

Also, I believe that *removing* the `/m` will make it even easier:

```
/(From.*?\s*Subject:\s*Two)/
```

[see here](http://rubular.com/r/KN8kxzeeDh)

If you might have lines in the middle, you need to use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(From[^\n]*\n(^(?!From)[^\n]*\s*)*Subject:\s*Two)/m
```

[see here](http://rubular.com/r/wEEb6nMGr3)

This regex does the following:

1. `From[^\n]*\n` - matches a text starting with `From` up to the end of the line
2. `(^(?!From)[^\n]*\s*)*` - matches zero or more lines *not beginning with From* ([negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))
3. `Subject:\s*Two` - matches a text containing `Subject:` [whitespace] `Two`

Comment: The input may contain multiple lines in between From and Subject: Two

Comment: @MohamedIrfanZubair - added solution for that

Comment: Can you explain me the RegEx.

Comment: @MohamedIrfanZubair - added an explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is another way:

**Code**

```
text.scan(/.*(From:.*?\n).*(Subject: Two)/m).join
```

**Example**

```
text = <<_
Line 1
From: person1@example.com
To: friend@example.com
   Subject: One
Line 5
From: person2@example.com
Line 7
   Subject: Two
Line 9
From: person3@example.com
   Subject: Three
The End
_

text.scan(/.*(From:.*?\n).*(Subject: Two)/m).join
  #=> "From: person2@example.com\nSubject: Two"
```

**Explanation**

The regex

```
r = /.*(From:.*?\n).*(Subject: Two)/m
```

skips all characters until it reaches the *last* string `"From:...\n"` that is followed (after some non-matching characters) by the string `"Subject Two"`.  Specifically:

- `.*`, being greedy, consumes as many characters as it can, including lines`"From:...\n"` that do not match the regex, up to the beginning of the first capture group.
- `(From:.*?\n)` is the first capture group, capturing `"From:` to the end of that line. `?` in `.*?` makes `.*` non-greedy, so that it stops at the first `\n` it reaches.
- `.*` consumes all following characters until it reaches the second capture group.
- `(Subject: Two)` is the second capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if subject =~ /^From[^\r\n]*\s*\S*Subject: Two/
    match = $&
else
    match = ""
end
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of a line
- `From` matches literal chars
- `[^\r\n]*` matches any chars that are not line breaks
- `\s*` matches any whitespace, including line breaks
- `\S*` matches any non-whitepace chars
- `Subject: Two` matches literal chars

**Multi-Line Version**

In response to your comment and new note, here is another version that will allow multiple lines between the `From` and the `Two`:

```
if subject =~ /^From(?:(?:(?!^From).)*+\s*+)*\S*Subject: Two/
    match = $&
else
    match = ""
end
```

Comment: FYI, added explanation. :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Added a Note in the question.

Comment: You're welcome, Mohamed. Added a Multiple Line version at the bottom of the answer, let me know if that's what you want. :)

Comment: zx, when I apply the multi-line version to `text` in my answer, I get `#=> "From: person2@example.com\nLine 7\n   Subject: Two"`. btw, you could also write that, `text[/^From(?:(?:(?!^From).)*+\s*+)*\S*Subject: Two/] || ''`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that's what he wants. :) The idea of the multi-line version is that there can be multiple carriage returns between the `From` and the `Two`.

Comment: Mohamed, you asked for the multiple line version. Did you try it, and did it work?

Comment: I've asked for clarification.